# terraform creating AD users and adding them to groups from yml

Tags: active-directory, yaml, terraform

We are trying to automate and self service privileged account creation with terraform, where the user would fill out a yml template with the necessary data, one yml file per new user.
structure like this: (displaying only relevant fields here)

```
user1:
  accountname: svc-d-ad-testuser1 # svc-env-app-description
  description: testing the creation of accounts in terraform
  department: wintel
  group_membership:
    - Temp-ServerGroup01
    - Temp-ServerGroup02
```

From these separate user yml files we are creating one big yml and terraform iterates through that to create the users.
That works fine. But then we would need to add the newly created users to the AD groups listed under each users group_membership.

For this, we need the `.id` of the newly created user in the

```
resource ad_group_membership "groups" "group"{
        group_id = <groupid>
        group_members = <newlycreateduser.id> 
}
```

We are trying to work out the syntax how to iterate through each group in each users group_membership , get the user.id from the `resource "ad_user" "u"` where the user in AD is created.
I was looking at `output` to somehow create new variables with the user.id but the variablename needs to be dynamic, or maybe I can create a map with the username as key and user.id as value? And then with the groups read that somehow...

Any help is greatly appreciated, even just on which constructs to use or some example for such a task.
thanks

UPDATE:
local.users look like this (parts stripped out):

```
{
    "user1" = {
      "accountname" = "svc-d-ad-testtf1"
      "group_membership" = [
        "Temp-ServerGroup01-MJW",
        ]
      }
    "user2" = {
      "accountname" = "svc-d-ad-testtf2"
      "group_membership" = [
        "Temp-ServerGroup01-MJW",
        "Temp-ServerGroup02-MJW",
      ]
    }
}
```

create ad user:

```
resource "ad_user" "u" {
for_each = local.users
  principal_name      = each.value["accountname"]
  sam_account_name    = each.value["accountname"]
  display_name        = each.value["accountname"]
  initial_password    = var.initialpassword # needs to be dynamically generated
  container           = var.container # OU should be generated based on team/area
  description         = each.value["description"]
  custom_attributes   = jsonencode({
   "userWorkstations" = each.value["servers"],
   "secretary"        = [each.value["supportteam"]],

  })

}
```

and group_membership is

```
resource ad_group_membership "group" {
    group_id = ad_group.group.id
    group_members  = [ ad_group.u1.id, ad_user.u2.id ]
}
```

I need a way to pull out the group name and add the user.id to the `group_members` list, but the user.id is only known after the user has been created by the `ad_user` resource.

Comment: Which is the provider? The groups already exist? If you create the user inside Terraform with a resource i am pretty sure you already have the id, just using resource_name.custom_name.id

Comment: Hi, so the groups exist already. 
You are right, we should be able to reference the user but the question is, how do I loop through all the users in the local.users , when I also have to loop through all the groups in local.users.user[*].group_membership?
I feel like I have to create a map from the values in local.users where `groupname` is key and a list of users is the value. Then I could loop through that for adding users to groups.

Comment: If is not too hard do something like that in locals, you can easly use a for_each construct, and assign values like `group_id = each.key` and  `group_members = each.value`. A possible workaournd could be build a module that iterate on `local.users.user.group_membership` creating `ad_group_membership` for a specific user and iterate the module (using for_each or count) on every user. Probably build a map can be more easy